# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.-Spring MVC + JDBC Template

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I am newbie to Spring MVC.
I was stuck by an error while running my project
**Error-The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.**
I have an entity class PatientInfo.
My jsp page is demo1.
My controller is Patient Controller.
The functionality i want to implement is Inserting values into database.
But i am not able to call my function(add-update2) in controller.

demo1.jsp

```
        <%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 align="center">Full Registration Form</h2>
<hr />
<table align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
    <form:form modelAttribute="patientInfo" method="POST" action="add-update2">
            <tr>
            <td> First Name</td>
            <td><form:input path="firstName"/></td>
        </tr>
               <tr>
            <td>Middle Name</td>
            <td><form:input path="middleName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name</td>
            <td><form:input path="lastName"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td>Gender</td>
            <td><form:select path="gender">
                <form:option value="" label="Select Gender" />
                <form:options items="${genderList}" itemLabel="gender" itemValue="gender" />
            </form:select></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Marital Status</td>
                    <td><form:select path="maritalStatus">
                            <form:option value="" label="Select Marital Status" />
                            <form:options items="${maritalList}" itemLabel="maritalstatus" itemValue="maritalstatus" />
                        </form:select></td>
                </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td>Nationality</td>
            <td><form:select path="nationality">
                <form:option value="" label="Select Nationality" />
                <form:options items="${nationalityList}" itemLabel="country" itemValue="country" />
            </form:select></td>
        </tr>
                 <tr name="tstest">
                     <td>Date Of Birth</td>
                     <td><form:input path="dateOfBirth" name="timestamp" value=""/>
<a href="javascript:show_calendar('document.tstest.timestamp', document.tstest.timestamp.value);"><img src="../images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Click Here to Pick up the timestamp"></a>
                     </td>
                 </tr>
<tr>
    <td>E-mail</td>
    <td><form:input path="email"/></td>
</tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Blood Group</td>
            <td><form:select path="bloodGroup">
                <form:option value="" label="Select Blood Group" />
                <form:options items="${bloodList}" itemLabel="bloodgroupname"     itemValue="bloodgroupname" />
            </form:select></td>
        </tr>
                <tr>
            <td><input type="submit"  value="submit"/></td>
        </tr>

    </form:form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller-PatientController.java

```
package com.app.ehr.api;
import com.app.ehr.domain.Bloodgroup;
import com.app.ehr.domain.Gendertype;
import com.app.ehr.entities.Patientinfo;
import com.app.ehr.domain.Maritalstatus;
import com.app.ehr.domain.Nationality;
import com.app.ehr.model.Patient;
import com.app.ehr.service.PatientService;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
public class PatientController {

   public PatientService patientService; 

   @Autowired
    public PatientController(PatientService patientService){
            this.patientService = patientService;
    }

     @RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(ModelMap map) {

        return "index";
    }

     @RequestMapping(value="/full-reg", method= RequestMethod.GET)
     public String fullreg(ModelMap map,Patientinfo patientInfo) {

        List<Bloodgroup> bloodList = new ArrayList<Bloodgroup>();
        List<Gendertype> genderList = new ArrayList<Gendertype>();
         List<Nationality> nationalityList = new ArrayList<Nationality>();
          List<Maritalstatus> maritalList = new ArrayList<Maritalstatus>();

        bloodList=patientService.getAllBloodgroup();
        genderList= patientService.getAllGendertype();
        nationalityList=patientService.getAllNationality();
        maritalList=patientService.getAllMaritalstatus();

        for(int i=0;i<bloodList.size();i++)
        {
            System.out.println("---------------------Controller"+bloodList.get(i));
        }
       // map.addAttribute("hello", "Hello Spring from Netbeans!!");
         map.addAttribute("patientInfo", patientInfo);
        map.addAttribute("bloodList", patientService.getAllBloodgroup());
        map.addAttribute("genderList", patientService.getAllGendertype());
         map.addAttribute("maritalList", patientService.getAllMaritalstatus());
           map.addAttribute("nationalityList", patientService.getAllNationality());
        return "demo1";
    }
        @RequestMapping(value="/add-update2", method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUpdate(@ModelAttribute("patientInfo") Patientinfo patientInfo) {
System.out.println("----------------------------------------- From Controller------------------------------------------------");        
//patientService.addPatient(patientInfo);
        return "redirect:/full-reg";
    }
}
```

Entity Class- PatientInfo.java

```
package com.app.ehr.entities;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Basic;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

/**
 *
 * @author HP LAPTOP
 */
@Entity
@Table(name = "patientinfo")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Patientinfo.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Patientinfo p")})
public class Patientinfo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "PatientKey")
    private Long patientKey;
    @Column(name = "PatientMRNumber")
    private String patientMRNumber;
    @Column(name = "IntPrimaryPhysicianKey")
    private BigInteger intPrimaryPhysicianKey;
    @Column(name = "FirstName")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "MiddleName")
    private String middleName;
    @Column(name = "LastName")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "Age")
    private Short age;
    @Column(name = "Gender")
    private String gender;
    @Column(name = "Nationality")
    private String nationality;
    @Column(name = "DateOfBirth")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dateOfBirth;
    @Column(name = "MaritalStatus")
    private String maritalStatus;
    @Column(name = "Occupation")
    private String occupation;
    @Column(name = "AnnualIncome")
    private String annualIncome;
    @Column(name = "BloodGroup")
    private String bloodGroup;
    @Column(name = "Email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "ModeOfPayment")
    private String modeOfPayment;
    @Column(name = "ModeOfPaymentAlt")
    private String modeOfPaymentAlt;
    @Column(name = "ExtPrimaryPhysicianName")
    private String extPrimaryPhysicianName;
    @Column(name = "ExtPrimaryPhysicianPhoneNumber")
    private String extPrimaryPhysicianPhoneNumber;
    @Column(name = "IsDeleted")
    private Boolean isDeleted;
    @Column(name = "Meta_CreatedByUser")
    private String metaCreatedByUser;
    @Column(name = "Meta_UpdatedDT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date metaUpdatedDT;
    @Column(name = "Meta_CreatedDT")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date metaCreatedDT;

    public Patientinfo() {
    }

    public Patientinfo(Long patientKey) {
        this.patientKey = patientKey;
    }

    public Long getPatientKey() {
        return patientKey;
    }

    public void setPatientKey(Long patientKey) {
        this.patientKey = patientKey;
    }

    public String getPatientMRNumber() {
        return patientMRNumber;
    }

    public void setPatientMRNumber(String patientMRNumber) {
        this.patientMRNumber = patientMRNumber;
    }

    public BigInteger getIntPrimaryPhysicianKey() {
        return intPrimaryPhysicianKey;
    }

    public void setIntPrimaryPhysicianKey(BigInteger intPrimaryPhysicianKey) {
        this.intPrimaryPhysicianKey = intPrimaryPhysicianKey;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public Short getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Short age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getNationality() {
        return nationality;
    }

    public void setNationality(String nationality) {
        this.nationality = nationality;
    }

    public Date getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(Date dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getMaritalStatus() {
        return maritalStatus;
    }

    public void setMaritalStatus(String maritalStatus) {
        this.maritalStatus = maritalStatus;
    }

    public String getOccupation() {
        return occupation;
    }

    public void setOccupation(String occupation) {
        this.occupation = occupation;
    }

    public String getAnnualIncome() {
        return annualIncome;
    }

    public void setAnnualIncome(String annualIncome) {
        this.annualIncome = annualIncome;
    }

    public String getBloodGroup() {
        return bloodGroup;
    }

    public void setBloodGroup(String bloodGroup) {
        this.bloodGroup = bloodGroup;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getModeOfPayment() {
        return modeOfPayment;
    }

    public void setModeOfPayment(String modeOfPayment) {
        this.modeOfPayment = modeOfPayment;
    }

    public String getModeOfPaymentAlt() {
        return modeOfPaymentAlt;
    }

    public void setModeOfPaymentAlt(String modeOfPaymentAlt) {
        this.modeOfPaymentAlt = modeOfPaymentAlt;
    }

    public String getExtPrimaryPhysicianName() {
        return extPrimaryPhysicianName;
    }

    public void setExtPrimaryPhysicianName(String extPrimaryPhysicianName) {
        this.extPrimaryPhysicianName = extPrimaryPhysicianName;
    }

    public String getExtPrimaryPhysicianPhoneNumber() {
        return extPrimaryPhysicianPhoneNumber;
    }

    public void setExtPrimaryPhysicianPhoneNumber(String extPrimaryPhysicianPhoneNumber) {
        this.extPrimaryPhysicianPhoneNumber = extPrimaryPhysicianPhoneNumber;
    }

    public Boolean getIsDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setIsDeleted(Boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public String getMetaCreatedByUser() {
        return metaCreatedByUser;
    }

    public void setMetaCreatedByUser(String metaCreatedByUser) {
        this.metaCreatedByUser = metaCreatedByUser;
    }

    public Date getMetaUpdatedDT() {
        return metaUpdatedDT;
    }

    public void setMetaUpdatedDT(Date metaUpdatedDT) {
        this.metaUpdatedDT = metaUpdatedDT;
    }

    public Date getMetaCreatedDT() {
        return metaCreatedDT;
    }

    public void setMetaCreatedDT(Date metaCreatedDT) {
        this.metaCreatedDT = metaCreatedDT;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (patientKey != null ? patientKey.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Patientinfo)) {
            return false;
        }
        Patientinfo other = (Patientinfo) object;
        if ((this.patientKey == null && other.patientKey != null) || (this.patientKey != null && !this.patientKey.equals(other.patientKey))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "com.app.ehr.entities.Patientinfo[ patientKey=" + patientKey + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you see the output of `System.out.println("----------------------------------------- From Controller------------------------------------------------");`?

Comment: No.. I dont see it. I think my error is with the @Model Attribute annotation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I think the issue is that Spring doesn't know how to deserialize the date your browser client sends when submitting the following `input` field in

```
<tr name="tstest">
    <td>Date Of Birth</td>
    <td><form:input path="dateOfBirth" name="timestamp" value=""/>
        <a href="javascript:show_calendar('document.tstest.timestamp', document.tstest.timestamp.value);"><img src="../images/cal.gif" width="16" height="16" border="0" alt="Click Here to Pick up the timestamp"></a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Spring doesn't know how to take the value that you enter into that field and convert it into a `Date` object. You need to register a `PropertyEditor` for that. For example, add the following to your `@Controller` class

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    sdf.setLenient(true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(sdf, true));
}
```

Obviously, change the `SimpleDateFormat` to whatever your client is sending.

---

On a related note, you're sending a 302 response by sending a redirect

```
return "redirect:/full-reg";
```

Remember that request and model attributes only live for the duration of one request. So when your client send the request to `full-reg`, none of the form input parameters you sent originally exist any more. You should re-think how you do this.

Comment: I was getting a similar message, but it turned out the model object I was passing (my equivalent of Patientinfo patientInfo) was missing values.

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same error this morning. The problem with my code was that I had declared a variable as an integer in my form binding object but on the actual form I was capturing text. Changing the variable to the correct type worked out for me

Answer (score 4):

This happens when the defined binding does not match to what the user is sending. The most common issues are:

- Missing PathVariable declaration
- Incomplete PathVariable declaration (for example missing value="variableName")
- Wrong data type, such as Sotirios Delimanolis answer above. If the Class of an input parameter cannot be serialized the request is not processable

So, in general, be sure that:

- Each PathVariable is declared
- A value is assigned that corresponds to value to be match in the path - `@PathVariable(value="myVariableName", String myVariable)` where the path defines `@RequestMapping(value = "/userInfo/myVariableName", method = RequestMethod.GET)`
- Each class declared for a PathVariable must be serializable.

Answer (score 0):

try with this (with `/add-update2` instead of just `add-update2`) and replace `modelAttribute` by `commandName`

```
<form:form commandName="patientInfo" method="POST" action="/add-update2">
```

Comment: No. It's showing error---The requested resource is not available.

Comment: `commandName` and `modelAttribute` are the same field. See - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21495616/difference-between-modelattribute-and-commandname-atributes-in-form-tag-in-sprin

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I try to create an object that has ID and NAME as attributes.
**ID is int, NAME is String.**
But my js set values like this
**ID = '', NAME = 'brabrabra...'**

After set ID = 0, problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and solved it by annotating my Date field with the `@DateTimeFormat`. In your case, you would edit your `PatientInfo.java` file to:

```
    import org.spring.framework.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

    @Column(name = "DateOfBirth")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = ${pattern})
    private Date dateOfBirth;
```

Make sure to replace `${pattern}` with a string representing the format that will be received (e.g. "yyyy-MM-dd").