# Error in hibernate form submitting?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i am using spring mvc with hibernate,
when i submitted a form is its shows an error

```
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect".
```

This is my form:

```
        <table>
        <form:form action="save" method="post" modelAttribute="staffSchedule">
        <tr>
            <td>date:</td>
            <td><form:input path="date"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Start Time:</td>
            <td><form:input path="startTime"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>End Time:</td>
            <td><form:input path="endTime"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Status:</td>
            <td>
                <form:select path="status">
                    <form:options items="${status}" />
                </form:select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Save">
            </td>
        </tr>           
        </form:form>
```

controller code is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView saveUser(@ModelAttribute StaffSchedule staffSchedule) {
    staffScheduleDao.saveOrUpdate(staffSchedule);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/list");
}
```

What do I do to correct this? I think the issue was in `date`.

Comment: That has nothing to do with hibernate

Answer (score 0):

Spring doesn't know how to deserialize the date entering from the frontend.
You can use `@InitBinder` to formatting date.

Try to use something like this to format your dates;

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    sdf.setLenient(true);
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(sdf, true));
}
```

PS: Sample code is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20616319/the-request-sent-by-the-client-was-syntactically-incorrect-spring-mvc-jdbc-te).

Comment: Thank you Semih eker.

its only showing converted date format. the error is still there.

Comment: You're welcome, you must modify the format {"MM/dd/yyyy"}  whatever client is sending.

Comment: Showing date in edit form which format used in SimpleDateFormat.  but still the error is there. mysql date format is yyyy:MM:dd.