# Spring error 400

Tags: spring-mvc

Hello and please for help,

I want list all data from mysql database and then modify them in the same view.

I create controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/list")
public class MainSpittleController {

@Autowired
private SpittleRepository spittleRepository;

@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public ModelAndView mainListAndModifySpittle(@ModelAttribute("spittle" Spittle spittle) {

    MainSpittleForm mainSpittleForm = new MainSpittleForm();
    List<Spittle> spittleList = spittleRepository.mainSellectAndModify();

    mainSpittleForm.setSpl(spittleList);

    /*view name, model name in jsp, object*/
    return new ModelAndView("mainSpittleView" , "mainView", mainSpittleForm);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/saveAll", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute("mainView") MainSpittleForm mainSpittleForm) {

    List<Spittle> contacts = mainSpittleForm.getSpl();
    if(null != contacts && contacts.size() > 0) {
        for(Spittle pm :contacts) {
            spittleRepository.mainUpdate(pm);
        }
    }
    return ("redirect:/");
}
```

}

And I create a JSP view:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Spittle List</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h2>List</h2>
    <form:form modelAttribute="mainView" action="list/saveAll" method="POST">

        <table BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="1">
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Wiadomość</th>
                <th>Termin</th>
            </tr>
            <c:forEach items="${mainView.spl}" var="contact" varStatus="status">
                <tr>

                    <!--  <td align="center">${status.count}</td>-->
                    <td><input value="${contact.id}" name="spl[${status.index}].id" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                    <td><input value="${contact.message}" name="spl[${status.index}].message" /></td>
                    <td><input value="${contact.time}" name="spl[${status.index}].time" /></td>

                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Zapisz" />
    </form:form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I hit "Zapisz" I got error message 400

> Description The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

On my different app I do something like this. Show data, pack them to the object, sent to controller and update the rows. But now I miss something and I don't know what.

For any help or suggestion I will be weary grateful.

Comment: Share `MainSpittleForm` as this is supposed to be your request model...

Answer (score 0):

Okay,

Problem solved.

And it was about the data that passes from the jsp to the controller.

If jsp returns the date, the controller does not know what to do with it because it accepts strings.

More specifically, m.aibin answered on this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803874/spring-mvc-http-status-400-bad-request)

It was enough to look for it better.

Regards