# Spring MVC, Hibernate, Oracle DB - Save is not working

Tags: spring-mvc

I get the following in the browser error while saving,

```
The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is 
perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request 
message framing, or deceptive request routing).
```

I don't get any error logs in the Eclipse console. I'm using Tomcat 9.0.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i'm stuck on this issue for quite a while now.

Many Thanks.

Below is my JSP code,

```
<div align="center">
        <h1>New/Edit Employee</h1>
        <form:form action="saveEmployee" method="post" 
modelAttribute="employee">
        <table>
        <form:hidden path="empno"/>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><form:input path="ename" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Job:</td>
            <td><form:input path="job" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Manager:</td>
            <td><form:input path="mgr" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hire Date:</td>
            <td><form:input path="hiredate" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Salary:</td>
            <td><form:input path="sal" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Commission:</td>
            <td><form:input path="comm" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Department No:</td>
            <td><form:input path="deptno" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Save"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form:form>
</div>
```

Below is my Controller method,

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView saveEmployee(@ModelAttribute Emp employee) {
        if (employee.getEmpno() == 0) { // if employee id is 0 then creating the
            // employee other updating the employee
            empService.addEmployee(employee);
        } else {
            empService.updateEmployee(employee);
        }
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/listAll");
    }
```

Below is my Service,

```
@Autowired
private EmpDAO empDao;

@Override
@Transactional
public void addEmployee(Emp employee) {
    empDao.addEmployee(employee);
}  

public Emp updateEmployee(Emp employee) {        
    return empDao.updateEmployee(employee);
}
```

Below is my DAO,

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public void addEmployee(Emp employee) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(employee);

}

@Override
public Emp updateEmployee(Emp employee) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(employee);
    return employee;
}
```

In browser i have the following when i inspect it,

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVCEmployee/saveEmployee
```

Form Data, view parsed

```
empno=7839&ename=KING&job=PRESIDENT&mgr=7839&hiredate=1981-11- 
17+00%3A00%3A00.0&sal=15000&comm=100&deptno=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from here,
[Spring MVC HTTP Status 400 - Bad Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803874/spring-mvc-http-status-400-bad-request)

You must bind the Date when you submit a HTTP POST. Spring does not know that this is a Date, it sees it as a String.

Add this:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
sdf.setLenient(true);
binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(sdf, true));
}
```

To your controller.